# Insert data in mysql using flaskext .mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am making a simple web form but i try to run this code its gives me an error I am new to python i don't know what this error means and could not find  solution online. here is a code:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from datetime import date
from dateutil import parser
mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'mraghib'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'raghib10'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'fyp'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    print(cursor.execute("select * from companylist"))
    addcompanyList= ("INSERT INTO CompanyList (Ticker, CompanyName, SECP_Sector_Code, SectorName,OutstandingShares,DemoSheetName,Years) ""VALUES (%s, %s ,%int, %s,%int, %s, %s)")
    datacompanyList = ("sdasd","adsda",142,"daasda",32,"sdadas",date(1977, 6, 14))

    cursor.execute (addcompanyList,datacompanyList)
```

[image]

Comment: what is the mysql type of 'ticker' ?

Comment: the types are(Ticker, CompanyName, SECP_Sector_Code, SectorName,OutstandingShares,DemoSheetName,Years) =(varchar(15),varchar(50),int,varchar(50),int,varchar(15),date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ddcompanyList= ("""INSERT INTO CompanyList (Ticker, CompanyName,SECP_Sector_Code, SectorName,OutstandingShares,DemoSheetName,Years) VALUES(%s, %s ,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""")
```

Comment: the error is gone but still not updating the database.

Comment: if you try to manual do this insert does it work ? in any mysql client.